# Calling API within API - jQuery/Handlebars

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I'm trying to call the two Reed job site APIs, one is to search for all jobs listed by an employer ID, and the second is to retrieve the data for all the job IDs found in the initial search. The data is coming through fine from the first API call, and I can get handlebars to place the relevant data onto the page with no issue. The second API will call and the data is visible in the JS console, but when it goes to place on the page, the console shows "Cannot read property 'jobTitle' of undefined". I know it's bound to be something simple, but I'm relatively new to the world of JS/APIs so could do with a hand!

Here's my html

```
            <div id="results">


                <table>
                    <tbody>

                        <script id="reedsearch-template" type="text/html">
                            <tr>
                                <th>{{ jobTitle }}</th>
                                <td>{{ locationName }}</td>
                                <td>£{{ minimumSalary }} - £{{ maximumSalary }}</td>
                                <td>{{ jobUrl }}</td>
                            </tr>

                        </script>


                    </tbody>


                </table>
            </div>
```

Here's my JS (removed my API key)

```
$(document).ready(function () {


var reedsearchHtml = $("#reedsearch-template").html();
var reedsearchTemplate = Handlebars.compile(reedsearchHtml); 



    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        async: true,
        url: "http://www.reed.co.uk/api/1.0/search?employerId=p8799",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("API KEY:"))
        },
        success: function (data) {

            console.log(data.results);

            for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
                var job = data.results[i];
                var jobHtml = reedsearchTemplate(job);
                $("#results").append(jobHtml);

                    var reedUrl = "http://www.reed.co.uk/api/1.0/jobs/";
                    var id = job.jobId
                    var url = reedUrl + id;

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "get",
                        async: true,
                        url: url,
                        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("API KEY:"))
                        },
                        success: function (data) {

                            console.log(data);

                            var jobDetails = data.results;
                            var detailsHtml = reedsearchTemplate(jobDetails);
                            $("#results").append(detailsHtml);
                        }
                    });



            }
        }

    });

});
```

Please be gentle and thanks in advance :)

Comment: You should look at promises.

Comment: Here is a great one... https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: What is `data.results` ? Can you copy/paste an example of that? I'm assuming it's probably an array and you're not accessing the first item. `[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it! Just needed the following change to the last 3 lines -

```
var info = data;
var infoHtml = reedsearchTemplate(info);
$("#results").append(infoHtml);
```

Took a lot of testing, but glad I got to the bottom of it :)